# Utorrent trackers list showing "Connection timed out."

Tags: macos, networking, bittorrent, utorrent

I can't seem to download any torrent. I can't find any peers, and the status of all my trackers is "Connection timed out."

I'm on Mac OSX Yosemite (10.10.1). I don't have my firewall turned on. I'm not using a proxy server. My internet provider is Comcast.

[image: Trackers tab]

Comment: Try with other torrent that you know for sure have lots of peers? It may be just this particular torrent. Can you try to connect or ping any of the trackers? Maybe torrent traffic blocked by comcast or your router?

Comment: It was failing for all torrents. I couldn't ping any website, so I checked the settings on my router. Turns out it was set to block ICMP and bittorrent traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my Comcast router was blocking bittorrent traffic by default.

Solution: Log in to router (http://10.0.0.1), go to Firewall, set security to minimum.

I discovered this because I couldn't ping any website or ip address. I wondered if my router was blocking ICMP, and when I logged in to the router, it turned out it was blocking ICMP, bittorrent and other types of traffic.